# How to Print a specific point from an array from another method ? #Java

Tags: java, arrays, printing

```
public class NewTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String [][] table;
        table = new String [4][4];
        for(int y=0; y<4; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<4; x++){
                table[y][x] = " ~  " ;
            }   
        }
        int y, x;
        for(y=0; y<4; y++)
        {   
           System.out.print(y+": ");
           for(x=0; x<4; x++)
               System.out.print(table[y][x]+" ");
           System.out.println();
        }                   
    }
    public void table ()
    {           
          System.out.println(table[2][2]);
    }
}
```

//this is the line where I have problems !
`System.out.println(table[2][2]);`

Comment: Slightly off-topic; but things get really confusing if you use the same name for a variable and for a method.  Here, you have a variable called `table` and a method called `table`.  I strongly suggest renaming one of them.  Usually, the best names for variables are nouns or noun phrases, and the best names for methods are verbs or verb phrases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `String [][] table` is *local* to the method where it is declared, and is, therefore, invisible to other methods of the class.

There are two ways of making it visible:

- Make `String [][] table` a `static` member in the enclosing class (because `main` is `static`), or
- Pass `String [][] table` to the function as a parameter.

The second solution is usually better:

```
// Here is the declaration of a method taking 2D table
public static void showTableCell(String [][] table) ...
...
// Here is a call of that method from main():
showTableCell(table);
```

Comment: So by leaving the first method the same the second method should be 
  //
public static void showTableCell(String [][] table)
  {showTableCell(table);}
}

//  if yes, it is not working !

Comment: @user3784420 No, the `showTableCell(table)` belongs in the body of `main(String[] args)`. The body of `showTableCell` is what you have in the `table` method right now (I renamed method so that its name is different from the name of the table).